# ReactJS - Event bubbling - Find out event chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have a UI section wrapped in a `<div` that has a onClick handler. Within that container, I have another element with a click handler which when clicked should only execute the element's handler and not the outer div's. For standard elements, this is easy by just preventing the element to bubble up with `event.stopPropagation()`. However, I'm using an element from a UI library, more specifically [Element's Dropdown](https://elemefe.github.io/element-react/index#/en-US/dropdown) element. Preventing the propagation for the top level button works, but I apparently cannot add a custom onClick event to the dropdown items and hence when clicking one of the items also the outer div handler is fired. The only way to solve this that I came up with is finding out if the event was already handled once by the Dropdown item.

Hence, the question, can I see if an event which is bubbled up has already gone through another event handler?

```
<div onClick={....}>
    <Dropdown onCommand={...} menu={(
        <Dropdown.Menu>
            {/* does not work */}
            <Dropdown.Item command="cmd1" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>DropDown Button</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
    })>
       {/* works */}
       <Button onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>Top level button</Button>
    </Dropdown>
</div>
```

Comment: `stopPropagation`?

Comment: I used stopPropagation, sorry for the typo in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Now you just need to find out whether `event.target` refers to a dropdown item or not. I guess based on that you can act accordingly when it gets captured in the `onClick` of parent `div`.

Hope this helps.